# Custom Entry Renderer with emoji button (Keyboard.Chat)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

How to create  custom entryrenderer with emoji (chat) button, like the one in the Xamarin.Forms Entry (where using Keyboard.Chat)

[image]

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. Why can't you use the Xamarin.Forms Entry with Keyboard.Chat instead of creating a custom renderer?

Comment: @MartinZikmund I need to customize the control (the underline color when its not focused), that's why we "must" use a renderer, so the renderer kills the KeyboardProperty

Comment: I have posted the relevant parts of the Xamarin.Forms repo in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are building a custom entry renderer, you will have to apply the same logic Xamarin.Forms uses to determine the input type of the target native input field.

**Android**

From the Xamarin.Forms [source code](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/bd31e1e9fc8b2f9ad94cc99e0c7ab058174821f3/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/KeyboardExtensions.cs#L19):

```
else if (self == Keyboard.Chat)
   result = InputTypes.ClassText | InputTypes.TextFlagCapSentences | 
            InputTypes.TextFlagNoSuggestions;
```

`result` is of type `InputTypes` which is then set to the [Android Entry control's `InputType`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/bd31e1e9fc8b2f9ad94cc99e0c7ab058174821f3/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/EntryRenderer.cs#L228):

```
Control.InputType = keyboard.ToInputType();
```

**iOS**

From the Xamarin.Forms [source code](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/bd31e1e9fc8b2f9ad94cc99e0c7ab058174821f3/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Extensions/Extensions.cs#L21):

```
else if (keyboard == Keyboard.Chat)
{
    textInput.AutocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationType.Sentences;
    textInput.AutocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.Yes;
}
```

Where `textInput` is `IUITextInput`.

**UWP**
From the Xamarin.Forms [source code](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/bd31e1e9fc8b2f9ad94cc99e0c7ab058174821f3/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/KeyboardExtensions.cs#L20):

```
else if (self == Keyboard.Chat)
{
    name.NameValue = InputScopeNameValue.Chat;
}
```

Where `name` is an instance of `Keyboard` type. This is however then [set directly in `EntryRenderer`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/bd31e1e9fc8b2f9ad94cc99e0c7ab058174821f3/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/EntryRenderer.cs#L231):

```
Control.InputScope = entry.Keyboard.ToInputScope();
```

So to simplify you just can do:

```
Control.InputScope = InputScopeNameValue.Chat;
```

**WPF**

Here Xamarin.Forms just set the default input type, as there is no special chat keyboard option.